# Discord Bot not responding when if statement is placed inside on_message command for event

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

The command "!hungry" isn't getting responded to by the bot. If I remove the if statement on line 19, the bot will respond to any message, but once I add the if statement for the specified string, I don't get any response back.

I need help on how to approach this issue. I have the code and error it gave [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYNN3.png):

```
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} is now connected!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
**    if message.content == '!hungry':
         await message.channel.send('Sure. Here you go.')
    await client.process_commands(message)**

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

This code without the if statement runs fine as the bot responds back to anything I type as seen below:

```
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} is now connected!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

**    await message.channel.send('Sure. Here you go.')
    await client.process_commands(message)
**
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the `message_content` intent, so you can't read messages. Refer to the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html) for more info on intents.

Also, consider just using the built-in [commands framework](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/index.html) instead of manually parsing messages.

Comment: I checked the docs on intents, couldn't rlly find any info on how to enable that specific intent.

Comment: What do you mean? The first thing on the page is an example of how to enable /disable specific intents https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html it's the exact same process for every single one so there's not gonna be an example for each of them...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I could make it work by toggling 'Privileged Gateway Intents' on Discord developer's page. You can find in the Bot section of your bot.

I used the below code :
(Sorry for the format I am still new to the Stack Overflow)

```
import discord

intent = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents = intent)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.name == client.user: return

    if message.content.startswith('hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run("token")
```

Comment: This says the same thing as my answer above

Comment: Yeah I tried this it worked. I was just confused on how to make all the intents true. Thanks.